# How can a helper dynamically call a component by its name like {{component componentName}} helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

How can I call inside a helper the equivalent to the Handlebars's helper {{component 'componentName' model=model}} to dynamically render components based on a programmatically changed componentName?

*I'm using ember-cli 1.13.8, with Ember 2.0.1.*

#### A bit of context

I have components called `cs-widget-image`, `cs-widget-text`, `cs-widget-form` that expect for a model `widget` based on its `kind` attribute.

So for a widget which its kind is `image`, I wanna render the component `cs-widget-image`, but I don't think that the logic to discover the name of the correct component should be knew by the model, so I'm not considering using the helper `{{component widget.componentName}}` on my view.

I think that the better would be have a helper that I can use on my views like:

```
{{#each manyTypesWidgets as |widget|}}
  {{widget-component widget.type model=widget}}
{{/each}}
```

On my mind, the helper `widget-component` would receive a widget model, and based on its attributes do a kind of "eval" and internally call the equivalent to `{{component 'componentName' model=widget}}`

Ex.: With `widget = {id: 1, type: 'image'}`

```
{{widget-component widget.type model=widget}}
```

should programmatically call the equivalent to HandleBars helper on template:

```
{{component 'cs-widget-image' model=widget}}
```

#### Disclaimer about a possible duplicate question

Before mark it as duplicate, I need to say that I really found some similar questions here on StackOverflow like: 
[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19441931/2659285)]
[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412559/how-to-render-component-helper-by-name-from-instance-field)]
[[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779572/emberjs-registerhelper-to-dynamically-render-a-template-in-ember-1-8)]
[[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259626/ember-component-based-on-model-type)]
[[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946805/how-to-dynamically-load-ember-components-by-name-in-a-template)], but all the answers are based on an elderly version of Ember that didn't work anymore on Ember 2.0.1 and ember-cli 1.13.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a helper and put the logic of building the component name inside of it. Let's call the helper `widget-name`, you'd use it like this:

```
{{component (widget-name widget) model=widget}}
```

If the logic is as simple as appending the widget type to the end of `cs-widget-` the following should do the trick:

```
{{component (concat "cs-widget-" widget.type) model=widget}}
```

I believe your `widget-component` approach is more complex, because you would have to have a computed property with the logic and then bind that in a `{{component` call. I hope the two suggestions are helpful :)

Comment: That it's a perfect workaround, and I also got it suggested on Ember slack. Anyway, I'm asking for the possibility to make a helper with a behavior similar to {{component}} to call it programmatically. Just to encapsulates all the logic on manipulating the name of the component.

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work for you?

```
//JS

widgetsWithTemplates : Ember.computed.map('manyTypesWidgets', function(widget) {
   widget.set('componentName', 'cs-widget-' + widget.get('type')); 
})
```

And in the template you just call the component by componentName property:

```
//HBS 

  {{#each manyTypesWidgets as |widget|}}
       {{widget.componentName model=widget}}
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: Also an easy way would be to make a common-component. When calling out the common-component you specify dynamic layoutName="xx" and the common-component has imported functionality of your components. So the actions and observers would work in common component.

Comment: Actually I'm purging the common-component way to have just the specific component called by a "dynamic component caller" helper.

Comment: Anyway, I don't wanna have any ember computed on the model/controller/top-level component answering which the name of the specific widget component.
Just because it is not their responsibility. I'm more into the @locks answer, but preferably in a way that a helper that call `{{component 'componentName'}}` programmatically in a way that I can manipulate the componentName on my will